# For Loop Issue, 'i' does not return to zero

Tags: c#

I'm not sure how else I can get a loop going that checks to find the letter, checks if it's capital or not by adding a 'C' (or not), and continues with the rest of the characters in the string. I'm not very good at explaining what's happening here as I'm sort of new with C#. But 'i' in the 'for' loop never gets reset back to 0, making it so that you receive the wrong output.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Encrypt
{
    class Program
    {
        static char[] alphabet = new char[52] { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'z' };
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            string output = Decode(input);
            Console.WriteLine(output);
            Console.ReadLine();

        }

        static string Decode(string input)
        {
            string output = "";
            foreach (Char c in input)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < alphabet.GetLength(0); i++)
                {
                    if (c == alphabet[i])
                    {
                        int intoutput = i + 1;
                        if (intoutput > 26)
                        {
                            intoutput = intoutput - 26;
                            output = "C" + intoutput + " ";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            output = intoutput + " ";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        return output;
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you want the output to be for example with input abcd and ABCD?

Comment: @JamesKyburz I would imagine `"abcd"` -> `"0 1 2 3"`, `"ABCD"` -> `"C0 C1 C2 C3"`.

Comment: I see, the loop was fine but you were overwriting the value in output upon each iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue isn't with resetting `i`, your issue is with

```
output = "C" + intoutput + " ";
...
output = intoutput + " ";
```

These do not append to `output`, they *assign* to `output`, meaning the previously assigned value gets lost. You'll want something like

```
output = output + "C" + intoutput + " ";
...
output = output + intoutput + " ";
```

Answer (score 0):

You're overriding output in each iteration.

output += "C" + intoutput + " ";
output += intoutput + " ";

Answer (score 0):

You say `output =` which **reassigns** `output` to a different value, it **doesn't add to it**, instead you want `output +=`.

Also, alphabetic characters are stored sequentially in character sets (`'b' = 'a' + 1`), this should work:

```
foreach (Char c in input)
{
  if ('A' <= c <= 'Z')
    output += "C" + (int)(c - 'A') + " ";
  else if ('a' <= c <= 'z')
    output += (int)(c - 'a') + " ";
}
```

**EDIT:** Another version:

```
foreach (Char c in input)
{
  if (Char.IsUpper(c))
    output += "C" + (int)(c - 'A') + " ";
  else if (Char.IsLower(c))
    output += (int)(c - 'a') + " ";
}
```

Both of the above are a lot faster than your algorithm since it doesn't have to loop through 1-52 values, just do 1-4 comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

```
  var output = new StringBuilder();
  foreach (Char c in input)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < alphabet.Length; i++)
    {
      if (c == alphabet[i])
      {
        if (Char.IsUpper(c))
          output.AppendFormat("C{0} ", i-26); 
        else
          output.AppendFormat("{0} ",i);
      }
    }
  }
  return output.ToString();
```

or

```
  return string.Join(" ", input.ToCharArray().Select(c =>
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < alphabet.Length; i++)
    {
      if (c == alphabet[i])
        return Char.IsUpper(c) ?
          string.Format("C{0}", i - 26)
          :
          i.ToString();
    }
    return "";
  }).ToArray()).Trim();
```

or with no loop

```
  //static List<char> alphabet = new List<char> { 'a', 'b', 'c'...};
  int i;
  return string.Join(" ", input.ToCharArray().Select(c =>
    (i = alphabet.IndexOf(c)) != -1 ?
      (Char.IsUpper(c) ?
        string.Format("C{0}", i - 26)
        :
        i.ToString()
      )
      :
     ""
  ).ToArray());
}
```

and finally with no alphabet array

```
  return string.Join(" ", input.ToCharArray().Select(c =>
    Char.IsLetter(c) ?
      (Char.IsUpper(c) ?
        string.Format("C{0}", c-'A')
        :
        (c-'a').ToString()
      )
      :
     ""
  ).ToArray()).Trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here your answer completes

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Encrypt
{
  class Program
  {
        static char[] alphabet = new char[52] { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'z' };

       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            string output = Decode(input);
            Console.WriteLine(output);
            Console.ReadLine();
       }

       static string Decode(string input)
       {
            string output = "";
            foreach (Char c in input)
            {
               for (int i = 0; i < alphabet.GetLength(0); i++)
               {
                  if (c == alphabet[i])
                  {
                     int intoutput = i + 1;
                     if (intoutput > 26)
                     {
                         intoutput = intoutput - 26;
                         output = output + "C" + intoutput + " ";
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         output = output + intoutput + " ";
                     }
                   }
                }
            }
         return output;
       } 
     }
  }
```